# Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cursor

I am new to android using kotlin.I am getting this error message in my log.

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.**

My Code Look Like this.

```
 @SuppressLint("Range")
    fun getAllTask():ArrayList<TaskListModel>{
        val taskListModel =  ArrayList<TaskListModel>()
        val db = this.readableDatabase
        val selectQuery= "SELECT *FROM $TABLE_NAME"
        val cursor:Cursor?


        try{
            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
            db.execSQL(selectQuery)
            return ArrayList()
        }
            if (cursor.count > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    val task = TaskListModel()
                    task.id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ID)))
                    task.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_NAME))
                    task.details = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TASK_DETAILS))
                    taskListModel.add(task)
                }while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
        cursor.close()
        return  taskListModel
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for `cursor.count` method. For example

`if (cursor.count > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst())`

Comment: It's Not working bro.

Comment: Try to check if the cursor contains all columns you want. Maybe the issue is with the database version not being upgraded after changes in the database.

Comment: I have checked all the code, but nothing find.

Comment: There must be a space after the * in query like, ````"SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME"````

Comment: Yes,i have do that also still getting same error.

Comment: Have you tracked that the error comes on which line number? post logcat details here

Comment: I think the wrong is that you are assigning to ````task.name```` = ````table_name```` from the cursor's column. you've to get ````task_name```` from the database and assign it to ````task.name````

Comment: i didn't understand your point can you please edit my question or repost my answer so I can understand.